# Private typedef used in public interface

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any reason to use private typedef's like the following?  I see the benefits for having the typedef for reducing possible errors from the duplication, but those benefits can be achieved with a public typedef as well.

```
template < typename T >
class foo
{
  typedef typename T::some_type reused_type;
public:
  reused_type go();
};
```

Comment: Can't think of one personally... Example?

Comment: Well, if it only makes sense internally then you can avoid cluttering the namespace by making it private. For example if it's a shortcut to an iterator type for an internal array.

Comment: In this case its used in the public interface - so its not strictly internal.

Comment: @Dave - making something private doesn't remove it from a namespace, although it's not clear to me what namespace you're trying to avoid cluttering.

Comment: @PeteBecker the `foo<whatever>::` namespace

Comment: @Dave - `foo<whatever>` is the name of a class, so it's only a namespace in informal usage. Regardless, making the typedef private doesn't make it invisible.

Comment: @PeteBecker that's kind of nitpicking; for all practical purposes it can be considered a namespace. As for making it invisible, well ok, I'll take your word that it would still show up, but as far as code-completion goes it depends entirely on the IDE you use.

Comment: @Dave - if you try to use the name in your code you'll get an error because the name is not accessible. If your IDE has some other notion of the visibility of such a name, it's wrong. The language is not defined by the tools you use.

Comment: @PeteBecker which was my point, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One practical reason to use `typedef` is to avoid having to write `typename` everywhere, and one practical reason to have it be public is to avoid the situation where the same thing (in this case, the type) is referred to by a zillion different names.

Comment: You make a good point - making it public does allow other pieces of code to couple themselves to that typedef ( ie: use it ).

Comment: @Sharkos, when its private you can't use it - when its public you can use it.  Not sure what you are saying, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Sharkos: it's all just a matter of how *easily* you can use the type outside of the class. in C++03 you had to invert code and use templating to get at it. with C++11 you can just use `auto`. but breaking and entering is different from being invited. so to speak.

Comment: @Cheers and hth, ok - so in the case of `auto` and `decltype(...)` in C++11 it won't create the coupling I was referring to.  I was suggesting that no other code can use the typedef by name because its private.  So I won't get in a situation where 1000 lines of code are using `bar<T>::reusable_type'.

Answer (score 1):

One reason I can contrive is that things should be public if and only if they form part of the published interface. Bear in mind that templates can be specialized, and if the type in question is only relevant to some specializations but not others, it shouldn't be public. For example:

```
template <typename T> class Foo
{
    typedef typename T::value_type some_type;
    some_type x;
public:
    int act() { return x.get(); }
};

template <typename U> class Foo<std::vector<U*>>
{
    typedef typename U another_type;
    std::queue<another_type> q;
public:
    int act() { return q.size() / 3; }
};
```

In the example, you promise that `Foo<T>::act()` always returns an `int`, but nothing else.